# checking if a given wiki page exists or not

Tags: python

is there a simple way to check in python whether a given wiki page exists or not?

For instance,

```
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ahfhowehlfadsfdas
```

doesn't exist.

Is there a one-liner to check the existence of such?

Comment: What did you try on your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will tell you if a url request is successful, or in other words if the url actually exists.

```
import requests

r = requests.head('<insert url>')
print(r.ok)
```

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach You're the one that is wrong. The code works, including for wikipedia page. Indeed wikipedia propose to write the article but the status code is still 404, meaning r.ok will be false in my example.

Comment: You are right. I changed my vote from -1 to +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that should work.  It returns `True` when the resource exists, `False` if it does not exist, and `None` if there was some other sort of error.

```py
import requests

def valid_site(url):
    r = requests.head(f"{url}")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return True
    elif 400 <= r.status_code < 500:
        return False
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: The advantage of using `HEAD` instead of `GET` is that the request just asks the server if the content is there, rather than asking for the page resource :)